# IOS SpriteKit Increment life count when game enters background

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, background-task

I have created an SpriteKit game (My very first game :) ), and i want when the user loses all his lives in the game, after a period of time the life count to be returned to the original and notify the user that his lives have been restored (this code is executed even if the app is in background mode), just like Candy Crush does it. The only way i see it done is by using background tasks, but according to the following link i should specify what my background task will perform, and i don't know what exactly to select for my situation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

So this is my problem, and i also want to ask if this is the right way to do what i want or is there another solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule a [UILocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILocalNotification) to trigger at a specific date/time to let the user know the status of the game while the app is in the background (or not running at all). You can then restore the life count when the game enters the foreground if the appropriate amount of time has elapsed.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to answer - got stuck with other projects. I tried your solution and it is exactly what i wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think Apple is really stingy about what apps are allowed to run in the background. I'm pretty sure candy crush uses push notifications to bug you about coming back to play. Push notifications use an external server to send notifications to a user about an app. Since its using an external server this isn't burning a users battery life by running an endless process in the background.  You can read more about push notifications here

https://developer.apple.com/notifications/